# In Python can i perform [if exists] inside the assignment of a key:value pair?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am doing an LDAP search and my results are what i want. I am putting the results into a dictionary. Some users in the results have a particular key:value pair and some don't. I want all users inserted into my new dictionary.
Here is the dict create inside a for loop.

```
ldap_output_Emply_dict[result_affil[i][1]['uid'][0]] = [
result_affil[i][1]['mail'][0],
result_affil[i][1]['uconnPersonPrimaryAffiliation'][0],
result_affil[i][1]['eduPersonEntitlement']
]
```

Currently only 16 users out of 1553 have the last item

```
result_affil[i][1]['eduPersonEntitlement']
```

I want all 1553 in my new dictionary.
this syntax i tried is not valid, is this even possible ?

```
ldap_output_Emply_dict[result_affil[i][1]['uid'][0]] = [
result_affil[i][1]['mail'][0],
result_affil[i][1]['uconnPersonPrimaryAffiliation'][0],
if 'eduPersonEntitlement' in result_affil: result_affil[i][1]['eduPersonEntitlement']
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of keying into the dictionary with `dict[key]` syntax, you can leverage the `dict.get(key, default)` method, which returns the value of the key if it is present and the default if the key is not present.

In your case it would be something along the lines of:

```
ldap_output_Emply_dict[result_affil[i][1]['uid'][0]] = [
    result_affil[i][1]['mail'][0],
    result_affil[i][1]['uconnPersonPrimaryAffiliation'][0],
    result_affil[i][1].get('eduPersonEntitlement', None)
]
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that and report back.

Comment: YES, that worked. I will try other persons solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

> can i perform [if exists] inside the assignment of a key:value pair?

Yes, in addition to using the dictionary's `.get` method as @6c1 mentions, you can use a ternary statement like so:

```
d1 = {}
d2 = {1:1,2:2,3:3}

d1[4] = d2[4] if 4 in d2 else None
```

In your code:

```
ldap_output_Emply_dict[result_affil[i][1]['uid'][0]] = [
result_affil[i][1]['mail'][0],
result_affil[i][1]['uconnPersonPrimaryAffiliation'][0],
result_affil[i][1]['eduPersonEntitlement'] if 'eduPersonEntitlement' in result_affil[i][1] else None
]
```

Comment: Vote it up so that it is apparent to others that it is also a useful solution.